# I'm trying to add multiple lines to a R Shiny plot that are based on a dropdown value

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a plot that already indexes a dataframe with the result from a dropdown menu, but I am trying to add another line to index a second dataframe in the same way to add another line to the chart. Both of the dataframes have the same dimensions.

```
  output$probability_chart <- renderPlot({
    req(input$countrySelect)
    idx <- which(input$countrySelect==FVI_DATA_ALL_COUNTRIES)
    plot(x = dates, y=Composite_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], type = "l"
         , xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Probability", col="blue")
    lines(Banking_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], col="red")
  })
```

I tried with the lines function but it didnt seem to work.

Composite_Probabilities_1_DF and Banking_Probabilities_1_DF are the two dataframes to be indexed.

**Correction, I realised I didnt set Y values, which now works, but another issue is that the Y axis values to not automatically adjust to the maximum of then data***

Comment: `lines` will not touch the axes, you'll have to redraw your plot for that.

Comment: With base graphics you'll have to precalc the limits, and pass that to the `plot` call.

Comment: OK, thanks guys. to add legends to those lines can I just pass something to the plot method?